# What is the minimum sdk allowed to publish apps in App Store?

Tags: ios, sdk, app-store

Helllo, I read some previous questions about this and I am now a little worried. Does anyone know where I can get this information, or if anyone knows something by experience please share.

Comment: I don't know what the minimum is technically!  It's pretty useless bothering with anything before iOS7.

Comment: Exactly, it is difficult to make a business case that you need to support iOS6.

Comment: Why do you want to know the minimum? The best choice you can make is to support the latest. Right now that is using Xcode 6.1 with a Base SDK of iOS 8.1. Using anything older is silly. Users want apps that work on the latest devices and support the latest APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting confused between **SDK** and **deployment target**.

EDIT:

At the moment, you can only submit apps that have been compiled with iOS >= 7.1

Apple published this news a few days ago:

`Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store 
must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6or later. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both  32-bit and 64-bit code.`

Lowest **deployment target** is 5.1.1 (due to 64-bit compatibility), as far as I know.

Many thanks to @rmaddy and @Anbu.Karthik for their useful comments!

Comment: Thank you, Yes I want to know about the SDK. Do you have any reference for this or you have by experience with some app?

Comment: I think you can send apps built with xcode 5 and SDK 7 until january

Comment: now apple has changed the deployment target is minimum 5.1.1 bro

Comment: Thank you, I am asking for the SDK and not for deployment target.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer is wrong. Apple is still accepting apps built with Xcode 5.1.1 which means you can use a Base SDK of iOS 7.1.

Comment: The Deployment Target can be as low as iOS 4.3 but there is absolutely no reason to support that far back.