# Is there a requirement to supply @1x images as well as @2x for successful iOS submission?

Tags: ios, iphone

Lets say our next iPhone project isn't going to support iPhone 3GS, do we still need to supply @1x images for successful submission of our application?

Comment: I don't think you can publish the app for 3gs at all, cause max iOS on that device is 6.1.3 and on store minimum is 7.1.

Comment: Fair enough. Then I don't see any reason to put the legacy @1x images into the application as long as it will not affect the binary submission to the app store.

Comment: Btw, the information that "Store minimum requirement is 7.1" is news for me. Do you have any link which proves it? Can we not submit applications to the store with support for iOS 6?

Comment: `Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6or later. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.`, but it also says `Lowest deployment target is 5.1.1` [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654138/what-is-the-minimum-sdk-allowed-to-publish-apps-in-app-store). I could be wrong, but I know I couldn't install the app on 3gs one week ago (new app)

Comment: But it doesn't mean that we cannot support iOS 6, does it? The fact that we include x64 source code does not prevent us from including x32 source code as well or am I completely confused?

Comment: Think you can choose deployment target and ask for minimum iOS 7.1. Hope you get a better answer.

Comment: Sure, but we can set the minimum requirement to lower as well if we choose to. I think it's up to developers to decide, but I think we are getting off topic :)

Comment: I don't think 7.1 min requirement is true, but in any case, there is no need for @1x resources if you don't support iPhone 3GS or older or iPad 2/mini or older.

Comment: @FilipRadelic, thank you. Did you by any chance submitted an app to the app store without 1x images? I'm worried about this, because it will cost us a lot if application fails the submission and we will need to go through the whole application and add 1x images.

Comment: Yes, I've submitted multiple iOS 7.0+ apps to the store without @1x assets and never had any issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have send a support request to Apple to clarify this and here is the official response from them:

> Hello Vladimir,
>
> Thanks for your patience while we investigated this issue. I’ve confirmed
>   with both App Review and iTunes Connect that there is no restriction on
>   including any particular asset size (1x, 2x, or 3x) in your bundle.
>
> If iOS needs an icon for a specific use, and an icon of that size is not
>   available, iOS will choose another icon and scale it to its needs.
>
> If your app is not iPhone-specific (that is, it can be run on iPad, either
>   natively or in compatibility mode), be aware that iPad 2 is not
>   Retina-class, and can run iOS 7 and iOS 8, and defaults to loading 1x icons
>   if available.
>
> Just for reference, Technical Q&A QA1686 App Icons in iPad and iPhone
>   lists all the icon sizes we recommend.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html
>
> Thanks,
>
> Jason.